# Getting 500 internal server error for API connect on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

We are getting below error while using Bluemix API Connect service. The same service was working fine few days back.

Error Message:

root request.py invoke_request: Response is: { "httpCode":"500", "httpMessage":"Internal Server Error", "moreInformation":"Failed to establish a backside connection" }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your backend API is down, but without more detail about your setup, it'll be difficult to help you further. :-)